# Grub is not loading, error: file ‘/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal-mod’ not found

Tags: ubuntu, grub, ubuntu-18.04

I cannot log into either of Ubuntu or windows installations in my pc and gives following error. I installed Ubuntu alongside with windows7

error: file ‘/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod’ not found
I tried to identify the partition to set the root and prefix but there wasn’t any partition with ext4 file system. Some partitions were ntfs and others file system unknown.

All the solutions I find in the google have a ext4 partition to recover with above steps. In my case, I cannot find such a partition. Can anyone suggest a solution to recover my system?

Comment: Best way to investigate the situation is to boot a live system from USB. Then append output of ```blkid``` to your question.

Comment: @Sameera download easyBCD and run it as a bootable and fix your boot order.

Comment: Error is typical of having an old grub install and booting in a different boot mode. Most Windows 7 systems are BIOS/MBR. Did you install Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode? May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair